# Using python how to display dns

Tags: python, python-2.7, psutil

Using Python, is there a way using psutil or something else to return the output of "ipconfig /displaydns" or something similar?

Spawning a cmd process and running the command is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a command, you can use the os library. Executing the command you've shown above is as simple as:

```
import os
os.system('ipconfig /displaydns')
```

If you want to store the output of a command in a variable, you can use:

```
x = os.popen('ipconfig /displaydns')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using dnspython's [resolver class](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html), which has a nameservers list attached to it.

```
import dns.resolver
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers
# Returns ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '8.8.8.8'] on my pc
```

Answer (score 0):

This python script I made creates a directory in widows user profile and copies windows dns information into a log.txt,So if directory does not exist it will create it. Hope it works for you.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import time
import os

def dns():

    path = os.system("ipconfig /displaydns >> %USERPROFILE%\DNS\logdns.txt")
    if path == False:

    
   
        os.system("ipconfig /displaydns >> %USERPROFILE%\DNS\logdns.txt")
        print("Please wait copying information........")
        time.sleep(5 )
        os.system("cls")
        print("Information copy complete.")
        time.sleep(3)
    

    else:

       

         print("Making directory please wait a second....")
         time.sleep(5)
         os.system("cls")
         os.system("mkdir %USERPROFILE%\DNS")
         time.sleep(1)
         dns()
        
dns()
```